# C++ What does the percentage sign mean?

Tags: c++

I got this c++ macro and wonder what they mean by code%2 (the percentage sign) ?

```
#define SHUFFLE_STATEMENT_2(code, A, B)
switch (code%2)
{
  case 0 : A; B; break;
  case 1 : B; A; break;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is for taking a modulus.

Basically, it is an integer representation of the remainder.

So, if you divide by 2 you will have either 0 or 1 as a remainder.

This is a nice way to loop through numbers and if you want the even rows to be one color and the odd rows to be another, modulus 2 works well for an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: % Does not actually compute the modulus for negative numbers. See Jerry Coffin's answer.

Answer (score 21):

In case somebody happens to care: % really returns the remainder, *not* the modulus. As long as the numbers are positive, there's no difference.

For negative numbers there can be a difference though. For example, -3/2 can give two possible answers: -1 with a remainder of -1, or -2 with a remainder of 1. At least as it's normally used in modular arithmetic, the modulus is always positive, so the first result does not correspond to a modulus.

C89/90 and C++98/03 allow either answer though, as long as / and % produce answers that work together so you can reproduce the input (i.e. -1x2+-1->-3, -2x2+1=-3).

For newer versions of the standards (C99, C11 and C++11) there's no longer any choice: integer division must round toward 0. For example -3/2 *must* give -1 with a remainder of -1. -3/2 giving -2 with a remainder of 1 is no longer allowed.

Comment: +1. In my opinion this is the only satisfying answer. The standard mentions the equlity (a/b)*b+(a%b)=a. Also, C++0x will add the guarantee that integer division always rounds towards zero. That makes -3/2=1 and -3%2=-1.

Comment: +1. And several times I have wanted to take the modulus of a negative number, but it's an instant guaranteed bug. It's a real flaw in C/C++: guaranteed to compile without a hitch, and might work on one platform, but instant (and mysterious) crash when compiled elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

It means the remainder of a division.  In your case, divide by 2 and the remainder will be either 0 or 1.

Comment: The remainder can be negative. The C++ standard only requires the equality (a/b)*b+(a%b)=a in case b!=0 and allows integer division to round towards zero (C++0x even requires it)

Comment: Although the remainder can only be negative if the dividend is negative (or the divisor, but that's 2 here). So depending what "code" is, that might not be an issue, and hopefully the programmer has thought of that when documenting how the SHUFFLE_STATEMENT_2 macro is to be used.

Answer (score 6):

It means modulo. Usually `(x % 2)` discriminates odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Thats the modulo. It returns whats left after division:

10/3 will give 3. - 1 is left.

10%3 gives this 1.

Answer (score 2):

Modulo returns the remainder that is left after division.  It is helpful when you're tasked with determining even / odd / prime numbers as an example:

Here's an example of using it to find prime numbers:

```
int main(void)
```

{
    int isPrime=1;
    int n;

```
cout << "Enter n: ";
cin >> n;

for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for (int j=2; j <= sqrt(static_cast<double>(i)); j++)
    {
        if(!(i%j))
        {
            isPrime=0;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (isPrime)
        cout << i << " is prime" << endl;
    isPrime=1;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's the remainder of division.
So like how 5 divided by 2 has a remainder of 1 because 2 goes into 5 2 times but that only equals four, and you got that little extra on the end

5 % 2 == 1

Note that division value isn't being calculated anywhere, so if you wanted both the whole total integer value of the division and it's remainder

```
int answer = 5 / 2;
int remainder = 5 % 2;
cout << "5 divided by 2 is " << answer << " with remainder " << remainder;
```

"5 divided by 2 is 2 with remainder 1"